# Lower the minimum delay for flagging comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, comment-flags, rate-limiting

Right now, comments can be flagged once every five seconds. It is quite common to flag multiple comments in a single thread. This takes far less that five seconds per comment (more like two seconds).

I request that the minimum delay be reduced to one second (or less if technically possible). Or, to zero because votes are limited per day anyway.

In general I noticed two annoying things about Stack Exchange rate limiting that seem to creep into product again and again: delays that are too long, and a frustrating experience when exceeding a limit (timer reset, lost input). The fact that this happens again and again looks like process failure from the point of view of an outsider. For example, high-rep users could just have an automatic 10x increase in all rate-limits.

Comment: High reputation is not necessarily correlated with quality of flagging. If anything, make the delay shorter for people with high volume of helpful flags, or leave it exactly as it is.

Answer (score 4):

If you're flagging multiple comments in a thread, there reaches a point where you ought to just flag the post it's attached to and ask a moderator to step in.

Once you get to the point where the flag delay annoys you, that's the point where you should ask a moderator to step in.

Comment: It is not uncommon that only some comments are chatty. Flagging 2-3 is not at all rare or outrageous. I imagine that processing them is quickly clicked through in the mod tools(?).

Comment: In another discussion, a moderator said that it is better to flag each comment separately, because it spares him from opening the question. I usually flag comment pairs or triplets like *You should expand a bit* ... *Thanks, done it*.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I didnt' say flag one for all in all cases; only in cases where you've flagged and waited so much that the delay actually bothers you.  If it bothers you only after 30 seconds, perhaps flagging multiple comments isn't the best use of time.

Comment: It sets in pretty early for me, but I've learned to live with it.

Comment: FWIW, it seems that individual comment flags get cleared much more quickly that flags on a post targeting all of the comments.

Comment: @BradWerth Comment flags are easier to handle than post flags, on the whole. Flagging the post with 'other' puts it into a far larger bucket than just flagging the comment.  Comment flags take a split second to determine their validity; Other flags typically take 30 seconds to a minute per flag.

Comment: when i am flagging just two comments it's frustrating to be made to wait 5 seconds

Answer (score -5):

This limit exists to prevent abuse. Abusers can flag every comment on a post, whether it needs to be deleted or not. The 5 second rate limit discourages these types of users and often prevents good comments from being flagged.

If you are looking to improve the site by flagging multiple useless comments on the same post, then you should be willing to wait 5 seconds between comments.

As George Stocker [mentioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272674/lower-the-minimum-delay-for-flagging-comments/272675#272675), there comes a point where it's better to custom flag the post and explain that there are many obsolete comments rather than flag each one individually.